# ComponentWillUnmount() not working in react native

Tags: react-native

ComponentDidMount() is not getting triggered when I am leaving the screen for payment process. On the successful completion of payment, I am coming back to the same screen but the view is not re rendered.
I have tried to clear the view in ComponentWillUnmount() while going to the payment page but no luck.
Can anyone please help me out with this!

Comment: componentDidMount() will only render once. If you want to re render the screen view when coming back from another screen, You can add eventListener of focus and re render the screen by giving any conditional statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using react-navigation(ex - stack navigation), the component will not necessarily unmount when you leave the screen.

To get the effect you want, you could pass some additional props when navigating back to the payment page.

```
navigation.navigate('Payment', { additionalInfo: ADDITIONAL_INFO });
```

This should trigger the react lifecycle methods which you can use to do custom behavior.

You can read more about this in react-navgiaction [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/#passing-params-to-a-previous-screen)